# How to get the output of a for loop using the variable of another for loop in Python-Flask

Tags: python, for-loop, flask

I don't know if that is the right term for my problem, I hope you can understand it. The purpose of this is to collect `files` from `ftp` with a combination of `account name` and `date` of the `filename`
I have this program in `Python` using `Flask Framework` with a Database `account_names`

The template have two dates - `from date` and `to date` and I will get the between dates of it. I created `for loop` to get the region in my Database and another `for loop` to get to get the dates between the two dates. In this for loop, I created variable `idDate` combines the `names` from database and the output of the `dates` and a `for loop` for files from `ftp`.

For this, I want to collect the files using the output in `idDate` to the `for loop` of `file`. This works on my another program that only gets a single date. But when I did it with a multiple dates, there's no output from my `print`

```
c, conn = connection()

data_name = c.execute("SELECT acct_value FROM account_names ORDER BY region ASC")
data_name = c.fetchall()

current_path = os.getcwd()
save_path = str(current_path) + '/logs/'
ftp_directory = '/R03/sqa/logs/'
chk_log_dir = os.path.isdir('logs')

strdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(from_collect_tab, "%Y-%m-%d")
endate = datetime.datetime.strptime(to_collect_tab, "%Y-%m-%d")

frm_month = strdate.month
frm_day = strdate.day
frm_year = strdate.year

to_month = endate.month
to_day = endate.day
to_year = endate.year

for names in data_name:
    region = c.execute("SELECT region FROM account_names WHERE acct_value = (%s)", (names[0]))
    region = c.fetchone()

    def daterange(date1, date2):
        for n in range(int ((date2 - date1).days)+1):
            yield date1 + timedelta(n)

    start_dt = date(frm_year, frm_month, frm_day)
    end_dt = date(to_year, to_month, to_day)

    for dt in daterange(start_dt, end_dt):
        out_dates = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

        idDate = names[0] + "-" + out_dates

        # print(idDate)
        if chk_log_dir == True:
            ftp = ftpconnection()
            ftp.cwd(ftp_directory + region[0])
            files = ftp.nlst()

            for file in files:
                # print(file)
                if idDate in file:
                    # ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + file , open(save_path + file, 'wb').write)
                    print(idDate)
                    # print(file)
            ftp.close()
```

Comment: You can remove SQL lines and replace them to real values. `data_name = c.fetchall()` -> `data_name = ['val1', 'val2', ...]`. It will be easier to understand.